# Getting podcasts to group together

Tags: ios, podcast

I am developing an app that creates podcasts. They are just .m4a files. However, even though I am setting the album name in the file, I cant seem to get them to group together as a podcast when I load them onto a device. I also set the artist, composer, genre, title, and a couple of other fields. They group properly in iTunes, but seem to all get lumped together in one big generic group on an iPad; the album is being ignored.

Is there a specific tag that needs to get set so iOS will group them in the Podcasts app?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're talking about creating what amounts to a Playlist for iOS 6, the new Podcast app does not support that functionality at this time. A quick search shows *lots* of people complaining about this, so I would say the hope is that this functionality will become available again in a future update. I wish I had better news for you.

Some reference:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4312284?start=0&tstart=0

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4262881?start=30&tstart=0

Comment: I don't mean a playlist, I just want the podcasts to group together under the same album. Many podcasts do this, so I know it's possible.